# Doctrine don't return all result - DQL, JOIN

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

This is my repository's function's code:

```
public function findLatest($count, $page)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery
        ('
            SELECT
              n.id, n.createdAt, n.title, n.titleCanonical, n.entry, n.movie,
              c.title as category,
              i as images,
              COUNT(com.id) as numberOfComments
            FROM WisJaCoreBundle:News n
            JOIN n.category c
            LEFT JOIN WisJaCoreBundle:Image i
              WITH i.target = \'Article\' AND i.targetId = n.id AND n.movie IS NULL
            LEFT JOIN WisJaCoreBundle:Comment com
              WITH com.target = \'Article\' AND com.targetId = n.id
            ORDER BY n.createdAt DESC
        ')
        ->setFirstResult($page * $count - $count)
        ->setMaxResults($count)
        ->getResult();
}
```

In table News I have a few records, but I get only one... I found problem, it's this fragment

```
COUNT(com.id) as numberOfComments
```

When I replace this for example:

```
n.id as numberOfComments
```

then all working good and I get all result. Why "COUNT" destroy my query?

EDIT------------------------------------------

I still don't know why that construction doesn't works, but problem is in same SQL, instead only "COUNT" had put nested query like this:

```
SELECT
  n.id, n.createdAt, n.title, n.titleCanonical, n.entry, n.movie,
  c.title as category,
  i as images,
  (SELECT COUNT(com.id) FROM WisJaCoreBundle:Comment com WHERE com.target = \'Article\' AND com.targetId = n.id) as numberOfComments
FROM WisJaCoreBundle:News n
JOIN n.category c
LEFT JOIN WisJaCoreBundle:Image i
  WITH i.target = \'Article\' AND i.targetId = n.id AND n.movie IS NULL
ORDER BY n.createdAt DESC
```

So, problem is solved :)

Comment: If you run it through a db interface (phpmyadmin), or via shell (`mysql -u root -p`) what error message do you get?

Comment: How do this? This is Doctrine query in DQL, not SQL...

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I misread and didn't notice that `COUNT(..` did give you a result.